# Issues with batch file to search registry and edit

Tags: batch-file, scripting, registry

I'm not so new to batch scripting and have done a small amount of scripts for various other things but this script has stumped me.

I've actually pulled this idea from somewhere else as I'm not that deep into the for commands just yet.

What I'm trying to do with this script is search every subkey within the HKU rootkey for a specific subkey path. If that subkey path exists it'll modify a key value within that subkey path. But it seems to keep failing with no error.

This is what I have right now:

```
for /f %%a in ('reg query hku') do call :loop1 %%a
goto :end

:loop1
for /f %1 in (reg query %1\software\microsoft\dynamics) do call :loop2 %%b
goto :end

:loop2
if Errorlevel 1 goto :error
reg add %1\6.0\configuration /v configurationfile /t reg_sz /d \ /f
goto :end

:error
echo Error has occurrd.
goto :end

:end
Pause
```

When I run this batch I get the following.

```
c:\Users\-username-\Desktop\test>for /F %a in ('reg query hku') do call :loop1 %a

c:\Users\-username-\Desktop\test>call :loop1 HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT

c:\Users\-username-\Desktop\test>for /f HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT in (reg query HKEY_USER
S\.DEFAULT\software\microsoft\dynamics) do call :loop2 %b

c:\Users\-username-\Desktop\test>
```

It seems like it just stops running? when I check the errorlevel after it runs it returns "0" so I'd think I'd at least see the error message come up?

Am I missing something small I'm just looking over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this to start with - see if what it returns is helpful to you:

This may need a later version of Windows - I'm not sure of the reg query options for earlier windows.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('reg query hku /s /f data /k ^| find /i "\software\microsoft\dynamics" ') do echo "%%a"
```

Comment: Right @foxidrive.  I should have caught that!

Answer (score 0):

You need GOTO :eof to return from the subroutines.

```
for /f %%a in ('reg query hku') do call :loop1 "%%a"
pause
goto :eof

:loop1
for /f "%~1" in (reg query "%~1\software\microsoft\dynamics") do call :loop2 "%%b"
goto :eof

:loop2
if Errorlevel 1 echo Error has occurred. & pause & exit /B 1
reg add "%~1\6.0\configuration /v configurationfile" /t reg_sz /d \ /f
goto :eof
```

Comment: This line is deeply flawed `for /f "%~1" in (reg query "%~1\software\microsoft\dynamics") do call :loop2 "%%b"`

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug(s). It was two places. RGuggiesberg, you are right. I needed the EOF in there. As foxidrive points out, the first line of "loop1" had some syntax issues. I was confusing myself.

Replaced:

```
for /f %1 in ('reg query %1\software\microsoft\dynamics') do call :loop2 %%b
```

with:

```
for /f %%b in ('reg query %1\software\microsoft\dynamics') do call :loop2 %%b
```

Now it's working fine. Thanks for the pointers!